# passing geoms to function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am interested in combining geoms for plots so I can reuse combinations of geoms. Take for example the following function

```
draw_curve = function(from = -pi, to = pi, fun = sin, plotfun = geom_line, length.out = 100, ...) { 
  x = seq(from, to, (to-from)/length.out)
  y = fun(x)
  sindf = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
  ggplot(sindf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    plotfun(...)
}
```

Now the following works:

```
draw_curve(plotfun = geom_point)
```

and even the following:

```
draw_curve(plotfun = function(...) geom_line(size = 3, color = 'red', ...))
```

However, the following does not:

```
draw_curve(plotfun = function(...) geom_line(size = 3, color = 'red') + geom_point(shape=21))
```

I can understand why it doesn't work because '+' is an overloaded operator that apparently expects a plot object on the left hand side and a geom on the right hand side. Also the result of plot+geom is a plot and '+' is evaluated from left to right so that is why ggplot works with the syntax for adding geoms.

Now my question is what is the easiest why to create a composite geom that I can easily pass into a function.

Comment: You just have your parenthesis in the wrong location `draw_curve(plotfun = function(...) geom_line(size = 3, color = 'red')) + geom_point(shape=21)` should work fine

Comment: That is of course another solution. Simply have the function return a ggplot object and then add the geom's to the result. That is remore the plotfun argument to draw_curve altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the geoms in a list:

```
linepoint <- function(...) list(geom_line(size = 3, color = 'red'), geom_point(shape=21))
draw_curve(plotfun = linepoint)
```